# c# Excel How to Change from [,] [.] to [.][,]

Tags: c#, excel, localization

Hey I want to change the Localisation from Excel,
which means on Programm start I want to set . for decimal and , for thousands separators in Excel.

when my programm closes i want to set it back to , . which is the german version.

Comment: Your program or (Microsoft?) Excel?

Comment: My C# Programm should change it in Excel

pseudocode : Excel.Localisation.Decimal ="." 
Or something like this

Comment: There is no Excel.locale. Excel is using the locale settings from the system http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-system-locale#1TC=windows-7

Comment: http://gyazo.com/9abf7d4566472760e4cfa996d0564281
but can select in excel that you dont want to use the System Settings so it should be possible somehow

Comment: Yes, sorry, had successfully displaced this;-). In VBA it is     `Application.UseSystemSeparators = False`, `Application.ThousandsSeparator = ","`, `Application.DecimalSeparator = "."` and `Application.UseSystemSeparators = True` to reset. Can you adapt this for C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive it could be achieved with 'UseSystemSeparators = false' like this.

> *(Example uses reference to Ecel 2007 PIA: C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\12.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll)*

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Application = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{   
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application excelApplication = new Excel.Application
        {
            Visible = true,
            ScreenUpdating = true,
            DecimalSeparator = ".",
            ThousandsSeparator = ",",
            UseSystemSeparators = false
        };

        _Workbook workbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Add();
        _Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];
        Range range = sheet.Range["A1"];
        range.Formula = "1,234,567.89";

        // re-set
        excelApplication.UseSystemSeparators = true;

        excelApplication.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: But this is only true for numbers, how about dates?

Comment: @Tomas could you be more specific?